# shared_ptr entirely on stack

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Assuming I know the stack frame will outlive all the copies of the `shared_ptr`, is there any way to create a `shared_ptr` to a stack object such that the reference counter is *also* on the stack so that there's no dynamic allocation at any point?

e.g.

```
SomeObject anObject;
std::shared_ptr::ref_counter refCounter; // Does this exist?

std::shared_ptr<SomeObject>(&anObject, &refCounter, [](SomeObject* obj){
    obj->DoSomething();
});
```

The goal here being to use `shared_ptr` for its reference counting rather than as a smart pointer.

EDIT: I'm gonna add some more explanation to make the reasons for doing this more clear.

I'm trying to create a token that calls a function when it and all its copies are destroyed for a threading library I'm writing. Each token is essentially just a wrapper for a smart pointer to a persistent object that holds the function and calls it in its destructor. Copying the token copies the wrapper (and thus the smart pointer), but not the persistent object.

Given that these tokens may be passed to many different threads the persistent object usually needs to be on the heap, but some of the time I can actually guarantee that a particular stack frame will outlive all the copies of any tokens it creates. In those situations the persistent part of the token can be created on the stack, forgoing any expensive heap allocation.

So in some situations the smart pointer *does* need to actually own the object it's pointing to, but in others it doesn't.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible.

Comment: are you try to keep the object on stack? or you need reference count?

Comment: and is there any reason you cannot use dynamic allocation? (in fact your Allocator can use stack memory if you just not want to use heap.)

Comment: You could allocate some space on stack with std::array or whatever, write a custom allocator which would allocate space from that preallocated chunk of memory and use `allocate_shared`. Only issue is you cannot (portably) know the amount of memory to preallocate - there is no way to know the size of shared_ptr's control block, and there is no way to allocate (portably) extra stack space on demand.

Comment: reference counting is literally an `int` incrementing/decrementing. Change to `atomic_int` for thread safety. What on earth happened that requires such an abuse of `shared_ptr`

Comment: `shared_ptr` is not wrapper around a reference counter. It is a tool for lifetime management; it may use a ref count internally, but that is *not* part of the contract.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to manage a stack allocated object with a shared pointer.

However, there should not be any need for it either. In place of the shared pointer, you can use a bare pointer or perhaps a reference. Since you know that the referenced object will outlive all users, it is safe.

---

> I'm trying to create a token that calls a function when it and all its copies are destroyed

For that, you don't want to use a shared pointer. You should just implement your own reference counter.

Comment: See my edit. The usage is a bit more complicated than the question suggests.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this but it would not be a good choice*.

---

```
SomeObject anObject;
std::shared_ptr<SomeObject>(&anObject, [](auto x){}});
```

[coliru example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/936e8f2b51c678b8)

---

*this does not use most of the functionality of `shared_ptr` and is a waste, and the count can be recorded in many other ways include implement you own counting class.

---

I really see no reason prevent dynamic allocation. Even if you can't use heap, the dynamic allocation can happens fully on stack.

Comment: This doesn't work; you get object and shared_ptr on stack, but shared_ptr will still allocate its control block on heap.

Comment: @AndreyTurkin true, as I mention in comment in OP's post, you can use a Allocator. Since I don't really sure what OP want to keep on stack, I leave that in comment. As with a Allocator, you can infact use `shared_ptr` at first place.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot there was such a constructor; easier than allocate_shared. Still no way to write such an allocator portably, though.